# 2D Collider wont trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

My player creates a barrier that should block the incoming attacks, but for some reason the collider wont trigger on the barrier, but its triggering just fine with the player gameObject as he takes damage and dies when hit by the projectile. I also tried with CollisionEnter and it had the same result. My barrierScript is this >

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BarreiraScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine("DestroyAfterLoad");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

     }
     IEnumerator DestroyAfterLoad()
      {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
        Destroy(gameObject); 
      }
      /* void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D other){
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "EnemyFlyng")
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
       }
      */
        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
      {
        if (other.tag == "EnemyFlyng"){
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

          }
          if (other.tag == "enemyProjetil")
          {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

          }
          }


          }
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure to double check your tags.

Answer (score 0):

`"enemyProjetil"` seems to be misspelt, although try not filtering it by tag and see if it will work, then you will know that your tag is the problem.

Comment: Yes, because you need a rigidbody to register the `OnCollisionEnter` or `OnTriggerEnter`

Comment: Collider2D doesn't check for collisions without a rigidbody component. Weird but it's in the manual.